# Prolog divide a list of numbers into two equal parts

Tags: list, prolog, sum, partition

Hi I want to write a function called perfect_part that takes a list of integers as input and if possible, return two sub-lists whose sum is exactly half of the total values of all integers in original list.
For example,

```
?- perfect_part([6, 3, 2, 1], L, R).
L = [6],
R = [3, 2, 1] ;
false.

?- perfect_part([1, 2, 3, 4, 0], L, R).
L = [1, 4],
R = [2, 3, 0] ;
L = [2, 3],
R = [1, 4, 0] ;
```

Here is my try:

```
listsum([], 0).
listsum([H|T], Total):-
    listsum(T, Sum1),
    Total is H + Sum1.

    subset([],L).
    subset([X|T],L):- member(X,L),subset(T,L).

perfect_part([], 0, 0).
perfect_part(Nums, Left, Right):-
    listsum(Nums, S),
    H is S / 2,
    subset(Left, Nums),
    subset(Right, Nums),
    listsum(Left, H),
    listsum(Right, H).
```

But if I run it, I got error message:

ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

How can I fix it? Am I on the right track to sovle this problem?

Comment: In your very first example, you have R = [3, 2, 1] ; but with the predicate yielding false.. sorry, but this is impossible. Either it yields false with all variables ununified/unbound, or true with one or more unified/bound.

Comment: In the first example, it returns the only combination of L = [6] and R = [3, 2, 1]. The 'false' means it has no other solutions I think.

Comment: Whether or not it comes back "false" would depend upon whether the solution with `R = [3,2,1]` was arrived at with a pending choice point, which depends upon the implementation of `perfect_part`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate subset/2 is missing, and it's an essential part to answer your question. Specifically, if sublists are contiguous, you can solve as easily as

```
perfect_part(X,L,R) :- append(L,R,X), listsum(L,S), listsum(R,S).
```

Then I would look for a more adequate replacement for append/3, like

```
partition([],[],[]).
partition([H|T],[H|L],R) :- partition(T,L,R).
partition([H|T],L,[H|R]) :- partition(T,L,R).
```

that leads to

```
perfect_part(X,L,R) :- partition(X,L,R), listsum(L,S), listsum(R,S).
```

*edit* Now, from subset/2 it's apparent the error cause: in base case, L is unbound.

Should be `subset([],[]).`, but it doesn't terminate. I wonder how you get the error...

*more edit* To avoid duplicate solutions, I suggest to break the symmetry with

```
perfect_part(X,L,R) :- partition(X,L,R), L @=< R, listsum(L,S), listsum(R,S).
```

Comment: oops, I forgot the subset part, now I update my question. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Also in your answer, for example, it returns L = [6], R = [3, 2, 1] and L = [3, 2, 1], R = [6]. How to remove this kind of duplicates?

Comment: @MichaelY this raises questions regarding your requirements on what's a unique solution. Are you handling the input as a list (where order matters) or a set? So does the answer given in `L` and `R` need to have elements in the same order as they appear in the input? Also, can some numbers appear more than once in the input list, and should they be treated as "different" with respect to duplication of answers?

Comment: @mbratch I am handling the input as a list. It’s okay if some of the partitions are essentially the same (e.g. due to duplicates in Nums, or when Left and Right have the same length). But I want to remove the duplicates as I mentioned above, ie.  L = [6], R = [3, 2, 1] and L = [3, 2, 1], R = [6].  I want it only returns L = [6], R = [3, 2, 1] if I query ?- perfect_part([6, 3, 2, 1], L, R).